# angular2(typescript) export variables from another file

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

In Nodejs I have a page called `variables.js` which looks something like this:

```
exports.var1= 'a';
exports.var2= 'b';
```

This file holds variables I use within in my application all in one place.

Then inside of another page I call this page using:

```
var variables= require('./variables');
```

Now I have access to the variable sin that page by using it like this for example:

```
alert(variables.var1);
```

I would like to do the same thing inside of angular2 (typescript). I have tried to play with exports and imports but I can't get it to work. How can I do this inside of angular2 using typescript?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**variables.ts**

```
export var var1:string = 'a';
export var var2:string = 'b';
```

**other-file.ts**

```
import {var1, var2} from './variables';

alert(var1);
```

or

```
import * as vars from './variables';

alert(vars.var1);
```

See also `Barrel` at https://angular.io/guide/glossary#barrel

Comment: When I try import "../variables" as vars; I get the error: Error TS1005: ';' expected. Ther eis a semicolon so I am not sure what it is complaining about?

Comment: It is now saying my ./variables.ts is not a module

Comment: are both files in the same directory?

Comment: Yes they are in the exact same folder.

Comment: Sorry, another error. I missed `var` after `export`. [**Working Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NupAdW1ovjBosotAhs63?p=preview)

Comment: You can also define your `var`s as `const`s to prevent them from being modified

Answer (score 3):

> have tried to play with exports and imports but I can't get it to work. How can I do this inside of angular2 using typescript?

Just use the `export` keyword and `import` keyword. This is just ES6 and magically works with TypeScript ;)

## Export:

```
export var1 = 'a'
```

## Import:

```
import {var1} from './variables';
```

## More

TypeScript modules are covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html